# hasAttribute("id") replacement before IE8

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have used

```
element.hasAttribute('id')
```

in my code to test whether the element has an attribute **id**. But hasAttribute API is only compatible with browsers after IE8.Is there a similar API or technique which I can use to check the availability of an attribute for an element in my case "id".

Comment: Test the return value of getAttribute().

Comment: Answered here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10131/will-this-test-to-check-if-an-element-has-an-attribute-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check `element.id` - it'll be an empty string if it's not set.

There's no need to use `element.hasAttribute` for those attributes that are mirrored by JS object properties.

Answer (score 7):

In the absence of the `hasAttribute` method, you need to use `getAttribute`. This *should* return `null` if there is no attribute set, and an empty string otherwise. In practice, some browsers return an empty string, so there's no way in these browsers of telling whether it is an empty attribute or no attribute at all.

```
if ((element.getAttribute('id') === null) || (element.getAttribute('id') === '')) {
```

Comment: This answer is more accurate.